# difficulties on array displaying month

Tags: php

on my drop down  i want to display month  1-12; but in my array  dropdown i only display 1 to 11 how can i fix this

```
       <?php     
          $year = date('Y', strtotime($edit_data['BIRTHDAY']));
          $month = date('m', strtotime($edit_data['BIRTHDAY']));
          $day = date('d', strtotime($edit_data['BIRTHDAY']));

          echo '<option value="00">00年</option>';

          for($m = intval(date('m')); $m > 0; $m --) {
              if($month == $m) {
                  echo '<option value="'.$m.'" selected="selected">'.$m.'</option>';
              } else {
                  echo '<option value="'.$m.'">'.$m.'年</option>';
              }
          }
        ?>
      </select>
```

Comment: this just add 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11  but there is no 12 on my month

Answer (score 1):

Change your

`for($m = intval(date('m')); $m > 0; $m --) {`

to

```
for($m = intval(date('m')); $m >= 0; $m --) {
                            ----^ // 0 is not > than 0 , you should check like this
```

Comment: tnx i already figure it out the other way :D
 for($m = intval(date('m'))+1; $m > 0; $m --) {